# getElementbyID Search with "With block variable to set" error

Tags: vba, loops, search, getelementbyid

been racking my brain over the last few days without any success. I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set", on the "If SignInButton > 0 Then" - how? Someone please explain. Thanks.

```
Sub SearchElement
Dim IE As Object 
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
IE.Visible = True        
IE.navigate "appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do"
Do While IE.readystate <> 4 
DoEvents 
Loop 
Dim signInButton As Object 
Set signInButton = IE.document.getelementbyid("ssoLoginFrm_0") 
If signInButton > 0 Then signInButton.Click Else 
End Sub.
```

I get "end if without block if"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But now I get "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set". Any ideas why?

Comment: id the ';' necesary in this line? IE.navigate "appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do";

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!

Comment: `If not signinbutton is nothing then...`

Comment: How silly of me. Of course, this is the way. Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unterminated `else` clause on this line:

```
If signInButton > 0 Then signInButton.Click Else ' Else what?
```

Comment: Thank you as well for the suggestion. As above, I get "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"..